# How can I save an Advanced Action on Drupal 7 installation when there's no save button?

Tags: actions

I am at the 'edit / configure an advanced action page' and I try to create or edit one of my "send email" actions (admin/config/system/actions/configure/...) However, I notice that the form has no save button.  It's not there whether overlay is on or off.  How do I save it?  My core and modules are all up to date as of today.  I am logged in as adminstrator and have rights to do everything (I checked that).

Here's my setup:
Drupal core 7.15
Includes: Aggregator, Block, Blog, Book, Color, Comment, Contact, Contextual links, Dashboard, Database logging, Field, Field SQL storage, Field UI, File, Filter, Forum, Help, Image, List, Menu, Node, Number, Options, Overlay, PHP filter, Path, RDF, Search, Seven, Shortcut, System, Taxonomy, Text, Toolbar, Tracker, Trigger, Update manager, User

Modules

Backup and Migrate 7.x-2.4
Chaos tool suite (ctools) 7.x-1.2
Content Access 7.x-1.2-beta1
Entity API 7.x-1.0-rc3
Features 7.x-1.0
Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha5
Job Scheduler 7.x-2.0-alpha3
Mailhandler 7.x-2.5
Pathauto 7.x-1.2
Rules 7.x-2.2
Strongarm 7.x-2.0
Token 7.x-1.2
Token Filter 7.x-1.1
Webform 7.x-3.18
Release notes

Includes: Webform

Themes
The Morning After 7.x-1.0-beta3.

Comment: Hi Q Beat What exactly do you want to do? I see you don't have the Rules module in your list. Have you considered using it to create a custom action? If are interested, I'd glady give you a rules based solution

Comment: Actually, I do have rules (Rules 7.x-2.2), check the list again. What I want to do is to add an advanced action, but could not. The form has all of the fields, but there's no way to save it. First I was trying to edit one already made up which was working fine by the way. I wanted to just improve upon it a bit. however, when I tried to edit it, I found no way to save the changes. So I thought the item was corrupted. So I deleted the action, and when I went to create a new one, I couldn't do that either because there's no save button. How do I get my save button back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Module "Token 7.x-1.2" is the culprit.  By disabling this module, the Save button again appears on the page.  Of course, to disable the Token module, I must also disable two other modules first.  Hence it's not a fix at all but a work-around because I have to re-enable this module for PathAuto.  I will attempt to submit an issue with the Token module.